# two mp3 file playing same time...? and white screen appearing for 5 secend by using onback and onpaused then screen become normal

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mp3

I am trying to make a soundboard app but facing a problem and want know 2 things...

Problem that facing...

1. I am using onbackpressed and onpause so that if any music was playing it should stop and not play in background...but when i press back it give a white screen for 3-5 second and start main activity...also when i minimize the app then go to it again it give a white screen and doesn't continue from the activity where i leave it..it restart...

things that i want to know...

1. if i play a mp3..it play wells..but when i click another mp3...they both keep playing same time...i want to know that how stop one playing if another one start...

   ```
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (mp != null)
            mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mp != null)
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kissymissy);

        ImageView a1 = findViewById(R.id.hugbut1);
        ImageView b1 = findViewById(R.id.hugbut2);
        MediaPlayer a2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
        MediaPlayer b2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);

        a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             a2.start();
            }
        });

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                b2.start();
            }
        });

    }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

All you need to set stop when you start other media to play

MediaPlayer mp;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (mp != null)
        mp.reset();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mp != null)
        mp.reset();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kissymissy);

    ImageView a1 = findViewById(R.id.hugbut1);
    ImageView b1 = findViewById(R.id.hugbut2);
    MediaPlayer a2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
    MediaPlayer b2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);

    a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            a2.start();
            b2.stop();
        }
    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            b2.start();
            a2.stop();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: yes but what if i use more item...like 8 to 10 music buttons...should i have apply same rules for every buttons?  or there is any shortcut way...?